# Emacs equivalent of 'y%'

Tags: copy-paste, vim-emulation

In normal mode in Vim, one can use `y%` to copy text between matching parenthesis. `y` starts the yanking command and `%` selects the matching closed or open parenthesis.

What is the Emacs equivalent of this operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would [*mark* the next sexp with <kbd>C-M-*SPC*</kbd>](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Expressions.html) and [*copy* the marked region to the kill-ring with <kbd>M-w</kbd>](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Other-Kill-Commands.html#Other-Kill-Commands).

You might find such questions more appropriate on [Emacs.SE](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `mark-defun`  (usually <kbd>C-M-h</kbd>, but in *c-mode* it's mapped to `c-mark-function`)

Jump between start and end of any region with <kbd>C-x C-x</kbd> to adjust boundaries of the selection.
Autocompleters like HELM show all functions that start with typed letters and their key bindings(if any).

**Or:**

<kbd>C-M-u C-M-space</kbd>

<kbd>C-M-u</kbd> *backward-up-list*, moves point to an opening paren or inner block.
<kbd>C-M-space</kbd> *mark-sexp*

**Or:**

<kbd>C-M-a</kbd> *beginning-of-defun*
<kbd>C-M-e</kbd> *end-of-defun*

...

<kbd>C-space</kbd> starts region selection. Move with any known key bindings. <kbd>C-x C-x</kbd> for adjustments.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. I am just learning emacs. Only been a few days and your answer really helps with navigating and selecting stuff in lisp files.